# Why is my string index out of range?

Tags: java, loops, indexing, nested, out

Writing a nested while loop for a coin flip program and I can't find out why my code won't compile.
The user input at the end is giving me the index out of range error. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
 Scanner lit = new Scanner(System.in);
 int numHeads = 0;
 int numTails = 0;
 int counter = 0;
 boolean tryAgain = false;
 String replayResponse = "";
 char replay = '0';

 System.out.println("Enter how many times a coin should be flipped");
 int numFlipped = lit.nextInt();

 do {

     do{


     if (Math.random() > 0.5){
         System.out.println("H");
         numHeads++; counter++;
     }

     else if (Math.random() < 0.5){
         System.out.println("T");
         numTails++; counter++;
     }


 } while(counter < numFlipped);

     tryAgain = true;

 } while (!tryAgain);

 System.out.println("Number of heads is " + numHeads);
 System.out.println("Number of tails is " + numTails);
 System.out.println("");
 System.out.println(" Would you like to play again? : Y/N ");


    replayResponse = lit.nextLine();
    replay = replayResponse.charAt(0);
    if (replay == 'Y' || replay == 'y') {
        tryAgain = false;
    } else {
        tryAgain = true;


     }

        lit.close(); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You exited out of the game.");
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
     }
```

Comment: In which line is it throwing the error?

Comment: It was the line with replayResponse.charAt(0); I closed the scanner now thanks to BlackhatSamurai but I seem to be getting an input mismatch exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scanning for int's you need to reset the input. Currently  the scanner is looking for the next int. So add `lit.nextLine();` like so:

```
 lit.nextLine();
 replayResponse = lit.nextLine();
    replay = replayResponse.charAt(0);
    if (replay == 'Y' || replay == 'y') {
        tryAgain = false;
    } else {
        tryAgain = true;

     }
```

You can also do:

```
if(lit.hasNextInt()) 
{
   numFlip = lit.nextInt();
}
```

To solve the type mismatch exception.

Comment: That did fix it! Although now I seem to get an input mismatch exception when I enter Y to try and loop the program. Is it another scanner error?

Comment: @EricSmith The scanner is a bit tricky when using int's and strings, etc. It has to do with the scanner, so I would close the scanner and then reopen if they want to play again.

Comment: I don't have anymore compilation errors now! Look's like I must have a logic error because when I input Y it outputs my exit game line

Comment: @EricSmith well if it worked, feel free to accept and upvote :)